# QT_HAS_BUILTIN warning

Tags: c++, qt, jenkins, qt-creator, qtcore

I am using Qt creator 5.8. I don't get any warnings on compiling my application with Qt Creator but I get the following warning by building the application with Jenkins.

> "C:\QtSDK\Qt5.7.0\5.7\mingw53_32\include/QtCore/qendian.h:53:0:
>   warning: "QT_HAS_BUILTIN" redefined"

I cannot deliver my project because of the warning. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the build output your CI is using Qt version 5.7.0. There is a bug reported for Qt 5.7.0 named [Fix warning: "QT_HAS_BUILTIN" redefined](https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-54068). It has been fixed in Qt 5.7.1.

Solution: upgrade Qt version in your CI system.